# Redux : dispatch not changing state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have some buttons, i want to change button backgroundColor when clicked. I tested color redux state on the console. Dispatch not changing redux state. here is the code and console;

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { initColor } from "./color"

export default function Question(props) {

const dispatch = useDispatch()
const color = useSelector((state) => state.color.value)

function toggleBtnBgColor(btn, correctAnswer) {
    if(flag) {
        console.log(color)
        if(color == "light-bg-color") {
            dispatch(initColor("dark-bg-color"))
            console.log(color)
            btn.target.classList.add(color)
        }
```

On the console output;

```
light-bg-color
light-bg-color
```

createSlice file;

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
export const colorSlice = createSlice({
name: "color",
initialState: {value: "light-bg-color"}, 
reducers: {
    initColor: (state,action) => {
        state.value = action.payload
    }
}
})
export const {initColor} = colorSlice.actions
export default colorSlice.reducer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `dispatch`, `color` is still set to the old color value (it does not get updated after `dispatch`). The `color` here is "stale" until the component gets re-rendered (`Question` function is run again). In that moment, `useSelector` will return the new upated `color`.
BTW: you should determine set the list of classnames depending on the outcome of the `useSelector` call and then set the names when you render your button (declaratively).

Simplified:

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { initColor } from "./color"

export default function Question(props) {

const dispatch = useDispatch()
const color = useSelector((state) => state.color.value)
const btnClassNames = color === "light-bg-color" ? "classname-for-light" : "classname-for-dark"

function toggleBtnBgColor(btn, correctAnswer) {
    if(flag) {
        console.log(color)
        if(color == "light-bg-color") {
            dispatch(initColor("dark-bg-color"))
        }
    }
}
return <button className={btnClassNames} onClick={...}>...</button>
```

Comment: it returns same background color for all buttons. I decided to use btn.target.classList.add(color) in the toggle function. It works! Many thanks for your help

Comment: Just one question, it works after first button. Even classList.add function places after dispatch function, it works when second button clicked